Kernel mode memory overflow occurs when Rabbit MQ is used
I am using Rabbit MQ as message queue middleware on a cloud server for WindowsServer 2012R2. Through the task manager, you will find that the memory space is constantly rising, and the memory resources will be consumed in about a week. Specific performance: memory increase, but did not find the extra memory is displayed on the program. The RAM Map shows that the extra memory is consumed by PageTable.
enter image description here
Page Tabel is growing at about 20KB/S.
I turned off the RabbitMQ service at night and found that there was no significant increase in PageTable, presumably due to a RabbitMQ problem.
Are there any incorrect configuration items or usage code that could be causing this problem? What should I do next?
Opening Processes in the RAM Map reveals a large amount of cmd.exe mixed with a small amount of erl.exe
enter image description here
